# webview and number of lines limit

Tags: android, html, xml, webview

everyone

I have a strange problem in a webview. When I use api level 19 emulator all the lines 
are displayed even when I expand all the "paragraphs"(nearby 1600 lines) but the lines 
are displayed partially(1200 lines) when I use api level 24 or 25.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
 <head>
 <title>title</title>


 <style>
div
{
text-align:justify;
text-justify:inter-word;
}
</style>







 <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" title="style de la page" href="afficher_cacher_div.css" />
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/visibilite.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="afficher_cacher_div.js"></script>

    <script>
function visibilite(thingId)
{
var targetElement;
targetElement = document.getElementById(thingId) ;
if (targetElement.style.display == "none")
{
targetElement.style.display = "" ;
} else {
targetElement.style.display = "none" ;
}
}
</script>

</head>
<body>




                <a href="javascript:visibilite('divid');"> <u> Solution:  </u></a>
                <div id="divid" style="display:none;">


                <br>  <br>


                    <a href="javascript:visibilite('divid2');"> <u> part1 </u></a>
                    <div id="divid2" style="display:none;">


                        <br>  <br>
      <u> part 1(important): </u>

      <br>  <br> 

      nearby 900 lines of codes 

            <u>part 1(important):</u>

                    </div>
             <br>
           <br>



                    <a href="javascript:visibilite('divid4');"> <u>  subpart 2: <br>
                        <br> (Display/Hide) </u></a>
                    <div id="divid4" style="display:none;">
                        <br>
                        <br>
           <u>subpart 2:</u>    
           <br>
           <br>


                        400 lines of codes


           <br><br>
            <u>Fin de la subpart 2.</u>


                    </div>
             <br>
           <br>





               <br>
           <br>


                    <a href="javascript:visibilite('divid5');"> <u> subpart 3: <br>
                        <br> (Display/Hide) </u></a>
                    <div id="divid5" style="display:none;">
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    <u>subpart 3:</u>



                     nearby   300 lines of codes
           <br><br>
            <u>Fin de la subpart 3.</u>

                        </div>




<script type="text/javascript">
//<!--
afficher_cacher('texte');
//-->
</script>



</body>



</html>
```

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"  android:background="@drawable/gradient9" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="720dp">



        <View
            android:id="@+id/View1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
            android:background="#00000000" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/View1"
            android:background="#FF00FFDD" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/activity_main_submenu2_button3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
            android:ems="20"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/Autre_exercice_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/activity_main_submenu2_title" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/activity_main_title" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/button_quit" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/activity_main_submenu2_title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="20dip" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

---

```
           function visibilite(id) {
         var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(var no=0;no<divs.length;no++){
        if(divs[ no].className=='divs'){ // on cible les divs dont la class                   est 'divs'
            divs[ no].style.display = "none"; // on les masque tous
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block"; // on affiche le div appelé
}
```

---

java(just the call of wiebview)

```
 webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());




        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);


        if (EXOnumero == 1)

        {     webView.loadUrl("file:///exo01x03x01.html");}
```

---

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `300 lines of codes`. Of vodes? Of text you mean?

Comment: a big part of those lines of code are only text , few of them are <br>, <u>, etc... Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your last comment "Thanks in advance for your help.. Very bad idea" Could you be more explicit ?